# Manually trigger Xcode 9 integration bot

Tags: ios, xcode, integration, xcode9, continuous

Is there a way to trigger the integration by shell script or apple script or whatever language can be used to trigger the integration of the Xcode 9 integration bot on some external event.

What I would like to do is to setup a CI build chain, which starts the integration of one or more Xcode 9 CI bots, for example, on commit of the code for the backend.

It must be possible, as it is also possible to start integration with a button in Safari... I just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question:
The REST Api for the Xcode server still seems to work for Xcode 9 CI.

So to start the integration of the bot with a certain ID we can use curl for example to POST a request to the server, which starts the integration:

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{}' https://your-build-agent.local:20343/api/bots/Bot_ID/integrations

replace "your-build-agent" with the URL of your bot in the network and replace Bot_ID with the ID of your bot.

You can get these values, if you right click on your bot in Xcode and select "Show bot in browser". There you can see the URL with the Id of the bot.